# Firebase database snapshot returns null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got this database:
[image]

and this code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference dataRef = database.getReference();
number = dataRef.child("planlekcji3").child("Monday").child("lessons");
number.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
         n = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
         number.setValue(Integer.parseInt(n)+1);
     }

     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error){

     }
 });
dataRef.child("planlekcji3").child("Monday").child(n).setValue(newLesson);
```

I've got this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

so "n" variable is null,
what's wrong with my code?

Comment: did u try toasting "n" ??

Comment: Either newLesson.getDay() or n is null...please be sure with showing both in log or toast

Comment: I've changed newLesson.getDay() to some string and error still appears, so "n" is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `setValue` part right into `onDataChanged` . Due to asynchronous nature of firebase listeners change in the `n` that occured inside `onDataChanged` will not be reflected on the outside atomically.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference dataRef = database.getReference();
number = dataRef.child("planlekcji3").child("Monday").child("lessons");
number.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
         n = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
         number.setValue(Integer.parseInt(n)+1);
   dataRef.child("planlekcji3").child("Monday").child(n).setValue(newLesson);
     }

     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error){

     }
 });
```

Hope that helps!